# Reshape dataframe from long to wide using merge function grouped by two factors

Tags: r, merge

I want to reshape a long dataframe to a wide dataframe by two grouping variables (resp & company) and three numerical respons variables (quality, amount, sense). I tried to do it with the dcast function, but it doesn't allow me to group by two variables. Can anyone help me out?

```
#Current long dataframe: two grouping variables (resp & company), three numerical respons variables (Quality, Amount, Sense)
resp <- c(1325851107,1325851108,1325851109,1325851107,1325851108,1325851109,1325851107,1325851108,1325851109,1325851107,1325851108,1325851109)
company <- c("Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Manual.nl","Manual.nl","Manual.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl","Dark.nl")
question <- c("Quality","Quality","Quality","Amount","Amount","Amount","Quality","Quality","Quality","Sense","Sense","Sense")
score <- c(4,1,2,6,8,10,5,5,7,4,6,7)
current <- data.frame(resp,company,question,score,answer); current

#Desired wide dataframe
resp2 <- c(1325851107,1325851107,1325851108,1325851108,1325851109,1325851109)
company2 <- c("Dark.nl","Manual.nl","Dark.nl","Manual.nl","Dark.nl","Manual.nl")
Quality <- c(4,5,1,5,2,7)
Amount <- c(6,NA,8,NA,10,NA)
Sense <- c(4,NA,6,NA,7,NA)
desired <- data.frame(resp2,company2,Quality,Amount,Sense); desired

#Using dcast function to reshape
library("reshape2")
dcast(current, resp + company ~ question, value.var="score")
```

The merge function that Parfait provided works. I provide here the script that did the trick (thank you Parfait ;)).

```
cols2keep <- c("resp", "company", "score")
df <- merge(current[current$question=='Quality', cols2keep], #merge two dataframes
        current[current$question=='Amount', cols2keep],
        by=c("resp", "company"), all=TRUE)

df <- merge(df,current[current$question=='Sense',       c("resp","company","score")], #merge third respons variable into new dataframe
         by=c("resp", "company"), all=TRUE)
colnames(df) <- c("resp","company","quality","amount","sense")
```

This solution works, but my real dataset exists of 53 respons variables. This method therefore is quite time-consuming. I tried the iterative approach of Parfait, but I get the following error.

```
dfList <- lapply(unique(current$question), function(i){
temp <- setNames(current[current$question==i, c("resp", "company", "score")],
               c("resp", "company", paste0(i)))
})

finaldf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., y=c("resp", "company"), all=T), dfList)
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

I am relatively new to coding in R and can't grasp what I have written wrong. I am happy with the solution I have now, but if there are more efficient solutions I am open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a merge on filtered subsets:

```
cols2keep <- c("resp", "company", "score", "answer")

df <- merge(current[current$question=='Quality', cols2keep],
            current[current$question=='Amount', cols2keep],
            by=c("resp", "company"), all=TRUE)

colnames(df) <- c("resp", "company", "quality", "quality_a", "amount", "amount_a")    
df

#         resp   company quality     quality_a amount amount_a
# 1 1325851107   Dark.nl       4   Didn't like      6    Maybe
# 2 1325851107 Manual.nl       5          Fine     NA     <NA>
# 3 1325851108   Dark.nl       1        Was ok      8     Fine
# 4 1325851108 Manual.nl       5 No, thank you     NA     <NA>
# 5 1325851109   Dark.nl       2          Sure     10  Not bad
# 6 1325851109 Manual.nl       7       Why not     NA     <NA>
```

For multiple groups such as *Sense*, continue to merge with a filtered subset:

```
df <- merge(df, 
            current[current$question=='Sense',c("resp", "company", "score", "answer")],
            by=c("resp", "company"), all=TRUE)

colnames(df) <- c("resp", "company", "quality", "quality_a", "amount", "amount_a", 
                  "sense", "sense_a")
df
#         resp   company quality     quality_a amount amount_a sense sense_a
# 1 1325851107   Dark.nl       4   Didn't like      6    Maybe     4    Nice
# 2 1325851107 Manual.nl       5          Fine     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
# 3 1325851108   Dark.nl       1        Was ok      8     Fine     6      Ok
# 4 1325851108 Manual.nl       5 No, thank you     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
# 5 1325851109   Dark.nl       2          Sure     10  Not bad     7     Yuk
# 6 1325851109 Manual.nl       7       Why not     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
```

Furthermore, for an iterative merge across all levels of *question*, consider the following:

```
dfList <- lapply(unique(current$question), function(i){
  temp <- setNames(current[current$question==i, c("resp", "company", "score", "answer")],
                 c("resp", "company", paste0(i), paste0(i, "_a")))
})

finaldf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., y=c("resp", "company"), all=T), dfList)
finaldf
#         resp   company Quality     Quality_a Amount Amount_a Sense Sense_a
# 1 1325851107   Dark.nl       4   Didn't like      6    Maybe     4    Nice
# 2 1325851107 Manual.nl       5          Fine     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
# 3 1325851108   Dark.nl       1        Was ok      8     Fine     6      Ok
# 4 1325851108 Manual.nl       5 No, thank you     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
# 5 1325851109   Dark.nl       2          Sure     10  Not bad     7     Yuk
# 6 1325851109 Manual.nl       7       Why not     NA     <NA>    NA    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait. This script is easy to use and resulting in the dataframe I hand in mind.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. Please accept to confirm resolution. Happy coding!

Comment: now I'm experiencing some difficulties when one of my grouping variables (company) consists of more than two levels (see the additional code I have added to the original post: #Grouping variable more than two levels, include "Senses"). I get this error: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical. Any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: See update with an added merge and even an iterative approach across all levels.

Comment: The iterative approach seems very useful and short, but it gives me the same error as I previously had: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical.

Comment: Which line gives you the error? The `merge` line?  Can you reproduce that error with posted data as I used with no issue? Check structure of your data `str(data)` to see if nested lists are included in columns. Remember `merge()` takes only two dataframes at a time.

Comment: The finaldf line gives the error. I have copied my script to the original question.

Comment: I have adjusted and simplified my original question. I am successful in using the merge function (for which I thank you :)). I have tried the iterative approach, but no succes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `tidyr`, the successor to `reshape2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

current %>% group_by(resp, company) %>% 
    # join answer and score into a single column to be spread to wide form
    unite(answer_score, answer, score) %>% 
    spread(question, answer_score) %>% 
    # separate joined columns
    separate(Amount, c('amount', 'amount_a'), sep = '_', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    separate(Quality, into = c('quality', 'quality_a'), sep = '_', convert = TRUE)

## Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
## Groups: resp, company [6]
## 
##         resp   company  amount amount_a       quality quality_a
## *      <dbl>    <fctr>   <chr>    <int>         <chr>     <int>
## 1 1325851107   Dark.nl   Maybe        6   Didn't like         4
## 2 1325851107 Manual.nl    <NA>       NA          Fine         5
## 3 1325851108   Dark.nl    Fine        8        Was ok         1
## 4 1325851108 Manual.nl    <NA>       NA No, thank you         5
## 5 1325851109   Dark.nl Not bad       10          Sure         2
## 6 1325851109 Manual.nl    <NA>       NA       Why not         7
```

Instead of using `unite` you could use `nest`, but `spread`ing list columns currently makes `NULL`s instead of `NA`s, which require a little additional wrangling:

```
current %>% group_by(resp, company, question) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    spread(question, data) %>% 
    # insert NAs with purrr::`%||%` so Amount will spread nicely
    mutate(Amount = map(Amount, ~.x %||% data_frame(score = NA, answer = NA))) %>% 
    unnest(.sep = '_')

## # A tibble: 6 × 6
##         resp   company Amount_score Amount_answer Quality_score Quality_answer
##        <dbl>    <fctr>        <dbl>        <fctr>         <dbl>         <fctr>
## 1 1325851107   Dark.nl            6         Maybe             4    Didn't like
## 2 1325851107 Manual.nl           NA            NA             5           Fine
## 3 1325851108   Dark.nl            8          Fine             1         Was ok
## 4 1325851108 Manual.nl           NA            NA             5  No, thank you
## 5 1325851109   Dark.nl           10       Not bad             2           Sure
## 6 1325851109 Manual.nl           NA            NA             7        Why not
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer alistaire, the first option already did the trick!

Comment: Just enquiring, I am wondering why you use this %>% signs. The script works, but I'm not really sure why :)

Comment: `%>%` is the _pipe_ from the magrittr package, which is now used by a lot of packages (including tidyr and dplyr here), particularly those associated with the _tidyverse_, of which the pipe is a major precept. The basic idea is that it makes code easier to read by avoiding nested function calls, lots of intermediate variables, or writing over the same variable, and reading in the order it executes. [Here's a much better explanation.](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying